# f.write(response.content, f) TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python

***Python version 3***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DELL/desktop/yoco/src/main/lib/modules/downloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    f.write(response.content, f)
TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

```
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import requests

repo_url = 'https://hide-ip/'
s = requests.Session()
package_name = sys.argv[1]
url = repo_url + package_name

response = s.get(url)
with open(package_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.content, f)
    f.close()
```

Please Fix this error

Comment: ```f.write(f"{response.content} {f}")```? You can use f-strings. ```.write``` takes only one argument

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you just want the GET response content in a file?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is dump the GET response text to a file then try this:-

```
import requests
import sys

BASE = 'https://hide-ip'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        package_name = sys.argv[1]
        with requests.Session() as session:
            response = session.get(f'{BASE}/{package_name}')
            response.raise_for_status()
            with open(package_name, 'w') as output:
                output.write(response.text)
    else:
        print('Package name not specified')
```